# Terraform failed to destroy aws EKS resource

Tags: kubernetes, github-actions, terraform-provider-aws

The following is my script - in the github actions, with terraform to destroy eks cluster.

we provide AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, these two credentials are coorected, because some other resources can be destroyed except eks.

```
name: "Terraform Staging Destroy"

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - staging
  pull_request:
    types:
        - closed
    branches:
      - staging

jobs:
  terraform:
    name: "Terraform Staging Destroy"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions: write-all
    env:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.STAGING_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.STAGING_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ../../staging
    steps:

      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Setup Terraform
        uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1
        with:
          cli_config_credentials_token: ${{ secrets.TF_API_TOKEN }}

      - name: Terraform Init
        id: init
        run: terraform init

      - name: Terraform Destroy
        if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/staging' && github.event_name == 'push'
        run: TF_LOG=DEBUG terraform destroy -auto-approve -input=false -refresh=false
```

When github actions run the above, the workflow fails, terraform complains about "unauthorized", this is error logs

```
Action=GetCallerIdentity&Version=2011-06-15: timestamp=2023-10-05T15:32:33.503Z
Error: -05T15:32:33.672Z [ERROR] provider.terraform-provider-helm_v2.11.0_x5: Response contains error diagnostic: diagnostic_detail="" diagnostic_severity=ERROR @caller=github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-go@v0.14.3/tfprotov5/internal/diag/diagnostics.go:55 diagnostic_summary="Kubernetes cluster unreachable: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials" tf_proto_version=5.3 tf_rpc=ApplyResourceChange @module=sdk.proto tf_resource_type=helm_release tf_provider_addr=provider tf_req_id=351e08bf-06b8-c3cb-68ba-e9a4d35a8314 timestamp=2023-10-05T15:32:33.672Z


Error: -05T15:32:33.672Z [ERROR] provider.terraform-provider-helm_v2.11.0_x5: Response contains error diagnostic: @caller=github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-go@v0.14.3/tfprotov5/internal/diag/diagnostics.go:55 @module=sdk.proto diagnostic_summary="Kubernetes cluster unreachable: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials" tf_proto_version=5.3 tf_rpc=ApplyResourceChange diagnostic_detail="" tf_req_id=b9a173e4-66c2-3552-0f36-1f31333d2e83 diagnostic_severity=ERROR tf_provider_addr=provider tf_resource_type=helm_release timestamp=2023-10-05T15:32:33.672Z


│ Error: Unauthorized
│ 
╷
│ Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
│ 
╷
│ Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
```

The above script can delete some other resources, that means terrraform can reach AWS. Seem it could not interact eks, so I add some permission policy to aws user such as AmazonEKSClusterPolicy and AmazonEKSServicePolicy, but still doesn't work.

I want to know what's wrong here? What am I missing? Any ideas for that?

Comment: There are newest versions of the `hashicorp/setup-terraform` action. Could you check updating the ref and check if the problem persists?